# Associate POSIX::open function to a namespace

Tags: c++, posix

I'm developing a control c++ library that needs to expose `controller::open()` function. However inside this function I have to call to the `POSIX::open()` function to open a file descriptor. The compiler complains I send Invalid Arguments to the controller function and doesn't understand I would like to call to the POSIX `open()` file function.

This is my code:

class declaration:

```
class PosixReadController {  
int open();
}
```

implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>   /* Standard input/output definitions */
#include <string.h>  /* String function definitions */
#include <unistd.h>  /* UNIX standard function definitions */
#include <fcntl.h>   /* File control definitions */
#include <errno.h>   /* Error number definitions */
#include <termios.h> /* POSIX terminal control definitions */

int PosixReadController::open()
{
  int fd = open("/dev/ttyf1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
  if (fd == -1)
  {
   /*
    * Could not open the port.
    */

    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyf1 - ");
  }
  else
    fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, 0);

return fd;
}
```

Error message (eclipse):

> Invalid Arguments: 'Candidates are: int open()'

Changing the call to open to the global namespace with `::open` doesn't help. Because I see the library already contains open function and I get the following error:

> Invalid Arguments: 'Candidates are: int open(const char*, int, ...)
>   ImageCtrl* open(image) ''

Any idea?

Comment: Do you actually have a `POSIX` namespace in your environment? Or do you just include the standard `<fcntl.h>` POSIX header?

Comment: Hum, how about sharing the code related to your problem dear 1304?

Comment: Most probably it's simply in the global scope: `::open()`.

Comment: I have just included the <fnctl.h>

Comment: After posting 67 questions on this site, you should know you need to show the relevant code and error message.

Comment: This is not good enough, because I don't own the library and the global namespace of this library already contains open function.

Comment: @RRR posting a few lines of relevant code and the exact error message shouldn't be a problem for you though...

Comment: @RRR Too bad. You can't 'move' someone else's symbol into another namespace, obliterating their original intent.

Comment: Do you get an error if you change `open("/dev/ttyf1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);` to `::open("/dev/ttyf1", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);`?  If so what is it?

Comment: @NathanOliver  yes. The error is: Invalid Arguments. 'Candidates are: ImageCtrl * open (Image),  int open(char *, int, ...) '

Comment: What happens if you add `using ::open;` to the function body before the call to `open`?  This is very strange.  It looks like it doesn't even find the posix functions.

Comment: Try this: put a dummy function `void dummy() {open("dummy", 1);}` and report which error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

> Invalid Arguments: 'Candidates are: int open(char*, int, ...)

This is extremely suspicious.  From where did you get this declaration of `open`?  Did you include `<fcntl.h>`?

The prototype should actually look like this:

```
int open(const char *, int, ...);
```

`const char *` would have matched the string literal you passed, but `char *` obviously does not because a string literal is not writable.

Comment: you are right, I can't copy from the server when I develop my code so I have to type everything manually and I missed the const. it's fixed now.